# Worst case for algorithm solving a game

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, algorithms

I came up with the following algorithm on a whim, and it doesn't relate to any deeper mathematics, but I'd like to see if someone can prove a connection it has to a sequence I found. You can think of the algorithm as a way to solve a game. Say that you have $n$ elements in some deranged order, and you need to put them in the correct order. You don't know the correct order, but every time you transpose two elements, for each one, you get told if its new position is the correct one. This algorithm implements a brute force solution to such a game.

Let $D$ be a derangement (permutation with no fixed points) on $n$ elements, written in one line notation. The algorithm proceeds as follows:

1. Identify the left-most element that is not a fixed point and label it $x$.
2. Transpose $x$ with the left-most element $y$ such that $y$ is not a fixed point and at no point in the algorithm did $x$ occupy the space that $y$ occupies.
3. Repeat step 2 until $x$ is a fixed point.
4. Go back to step 1 and repeat until you get the identity permutation.

For example, say we start with $53421$. Here's the process the algorithm takes: $53421\to 35421\to 34521\to 34251\to 34215\to 24315\to 42315\to 12345$.

We label $5$ as $x$ and keep transposing it with the element to the right of it until it is the last element. We then label $3$ as $x$. However, we don't transpose $3$ with $4$ since $3$ has already been in the second place at some point in the algorithm, so we transpose it with $2$ instead. Then we label $2$ as $x$ and transpose it with $4$. Finally, we label $4$ as $x$ and transpose it with $1$, the only other non-fixed point, completing the algorithm.

What I'm interested in is the number of transpositions required for derangements- in particular, for derangements of length $n$, what is the largest number of transpositions required. The previous derangement, along with $54123$, are the derangements of length $5$ using the most transpositions, with the algorithm taking $7$ transpositions for each.

[I've written code](https://repl.it/@Toncas/FriendlyRemarkableExecutables) to produce, for each $n$, the "worst case" derangements and the number of transpositions they require. Here's some of the data:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & \textrm{"Worst case" derangements}                                                                                                                       & \textrm{Number of transpositions} \\
2 & 21                                                                                                                                              & 1                        \\
3 & 231, 312                                                                                                                                        & 2                        \\
4 & 4312                                                                                                                                            & 5                        \\
5 & 53421, 54123                                                                                                                                    & 7                        \\
6 & 654213                                                                                                                                          & 11                       \\
7 & 7645123, 7645231                                                                                                                                & 15                       \\
8 & 87561342                                                                                                                                        & 21                       \\
9 & 985617324, 985617432, 985762413, 985763421, 986713425 & 25\\
10 & 0968174235
& 32
\end{array}

Interestingly, the number of worst case derangements seems to alternate between $1$ and $2$ until we reach $n=9$. The other interesting result is that the worst case number of transpositions matches the sequence [A084935](https://oeis.org/A084935) on OEIS. I don't see any obvious connections between that sequence and what I'm counting here, but they do agree on the first $10$ entries. Are these two sequences equal?

Comment: I can't quite grog your algorithm but the best one I've found is the string/merge sort that I used on mainframes years ago. You receive things and start an output string with the first one, continuing the string until an input is out-of-order. Then you start a new string and continue as with the first until you find another out-of-order input. (oddly, the number of strings is usually a Fibonacci number).  After the first pass, you sample the first and subsequent members of all strings, again starting a new  output string when none is in-order. Continue until you have one string.

Comment: @poetasis I don't know much about algorithms, so "sorting algorithm" may have beena  misnomer. Say I give you some objects, tell you that they're all in the wrong place, but I don't tell you what the right order is. After you swap two objects, I'll tell you if you've put one (or both) in the right place. You pick the first object, and keep swapping it with another until I tell you that you've put it in the right place. You then restart the process with a new object. You'll never move something that's already in its right place, or move an object to a place it has already occupied.

Comment: I've used the bubble sort which seems like what you are talking about and it works but it is one of the least efficient.

Comment: "This algorithm implements a brute force solution to such a [position guessing] game." -- IMHO this description should be front and center (incl. perhaps in the title).  The problem & algorithm have really nothing to do with sorting.  The numbers aren't really sorted, and there are no $>$ comparisons anywhere.  Instead, each number represents where that object's "correct" position is, in the guessing game.

Comment: @antkam Good point- I've edited the problem to put the game description in the beginning.